# Compute data.frame column averages by date

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dataframe, average

I have a data.frame in R where one column is a list of dates (many of which are duplicates), whereas the other column is a temperature recorded on that date. The columns in question look like this (but is several thousand rows and a few other unnecessary cols):

```
Date    |    Temp
-----------------
1/2/13     34.4
1/2/13     36.4
1/2/13     34.3
1/4/13     45.6
1/4/13     33.5
1/5/13     45.2
```

I need to find a way of getting a daily average for temperature. So ideally, I could tell R to loop through the data.frame and for every date that matched, give me an average for the temperature that day. I've been googling and I know loops in R are possible, but I can't wrap my head around this conceptually given what little I know about R code.

I know I can pull out a single column and average it (i.e. `mean(data.frame[[2]])`) but I'm utterly lost on how to tell R to match that mean to a single value located in the first column.

Additionally, how could I generate an average for every seven calendar days (regardless of how many entries exist for a single day)? So, a **seven day rolling average**, i.e. if my date range starts at 1/1/13 I'd get an average for all temps taken between 1/1/13 and 1/7/13, and then between 1/8/13 and 1/15/13 and so on...

Any assistance helping me grasp R loops is much appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT**

Here's the output of `dput(head(my.dataframe))` **PLEASE NOTE:** I edited down both "date" and "timestamp" because they both go on for several thousand entries otherwise:

```
structure(list(RECID = 579:584, SITEID = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 
101L, 101L, 101L), MONTH = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), DAY = c(7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), DATE = structure(c(34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
34L), .Label = c("10/1/2013", "10/10/2013", "10/11/2013", "10/12/2013", 
"10/2/2013", "10/3/2013", "10/4/2013", "10/5/2013", "10/6/2013", 
"10/7/2013", "10/8/2013", "10/9/2013", "6/10/2013", "6/11/2013","9/9/2013"), class = "factor"), TIMESTAMP = structure(784:789, .Label = c("10/1/2013 0:00", 
"10/1/2013 1:00", "10/1/2013 10:00", "10/1/2013 11:00", "10/1/2013 12:00", 
"10/1/2013 13:00", "10/1/2013 14:00", "10/1/2013 15:00", "10/1/2013 16:00", 
"10/1/2013 17:00", "10/1/2013 18:00", "10/1/2013 19:00", "10/1/2013 2:00"), class = "factor"), TEMP = c(23.376, 23.376, 23.833, 24.146, 
24.219, 24.05), X.C = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("RECID", 
"SITEID", "MONTH", "DAY", "DATE", "TIMESTAMP", "TEMP", "X.C"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: That `dput` looks nothing like your sample data!

Comment: *'generate average for every 7 calendar days'*: do you mean ***'average-by-week-of-year'***, or ***'moving 7-day average'***?

Comment: Also, note that R is case-sensitive. `Date` is not the same as `DATE`.

Comment: The output of `dput(head(my.dataframe), n=20)` or whatever is fine.

Comment: I got my daily average after I figured out the case sensitive bit. :) I'm now pondering rolling average... I'll edit question but @smci, see my comment to you.

Comment: @TheNovice, that's actually a different question entirely, but my advice stands: Look at the "xts" package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(plyr)

ddply(df, .(Date), summarize, daily_mean_Temp = mean(Temp))
```

This is a simple example of the Split-Apply-Combine paradigm.

Alternative #1 as Ananda Mahto mentions, `dplyr` package is a higher-performance rewrite of `plyr`. He shows the syntax.

Alternative #2: `aggregate()` is also functionally equivalent, just has fewer bells-and-whistles than `plyr/dplyr`.

---

Additionally *'generate average for every 7 calendar days'*: do you mean ***'average-by-week-of-year'***, or ***'moving 7-day average (trailing/leading/centered)'***?

Comment: Good, succinct answer! OP: you probably want to explore the plyr package more generally, too, if you're going to be iterating through data frames - it's endlessly useful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @smci, I went ahead and downloaded plyr. I probably I needed to add more specific data because I'm getting the following error when I try your code: Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors

Any ideas?

Comment: I strongly recommend you skip `plyr` and jump right to `dplyr`. Cleaner syntax, much better performance, newer code, nicer idiom, more extensible. Trust me on this.

Comment: I downloaded it. I'm getting the following error now - Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Date' not found

Which to me signals I need to do something more w/ my columns that simply import my CSV?

Comment: You're running @AnandaMahto's sample dplyr code, right? If yes, post the code you're running that is not working - as an addendum above in your original question, not here in the comments.

Comment: @smci - I mean MOVING average. Rolling average. So if my data starts on 1/1/13 I'd average all temps until 1/7/13... then my next average would be in range 1/8/13 - 1/15/13 and so on...

Comment: Actually that's **not** a moving-average. It looks like ***'average-by-week-of-year'*** not 'moving 7-day average'. Because you don't calculate an average for each day from the previous (or centered) 7 days for e.g. 1/10/2013 from 1/4/2013..1/10/2013.

Answer (score 9):

Here are a few options:

```
aggregate(Temp ~ Date, mydf, mean)
#     Date     Temp
# 1 1/2/13 35.03333
# 2 1/4/13 39.55000
# 3 1/5/13 45.20000

library(dplyr)
mydf %.% group_by(Date) %.% summarise(mean(Temp))
# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
# 
#     Date mean(Temp)
# 1 1/2/13   35.03333
# 2 1/4/13   39.55000
# 3 1/5/13   45.20000

library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(mydf)
DT[, mean(Temp), by = Date]
#      Date       V1
# 1: 1/2/13 35.03333
# 2: 1/4/13 39.55000
# 3: 1/5/13 45.20000

library(xts)
dfX <- xts(mydf$Temp, as.Date(mydf$Date))
apply.daily(dfX, mean)
#             [,1]
# 1-02-13 35.03333
# 1-04-13 39.55000
# 1-05-13 45.20000
```

---

Since you are dealing with dates, you should explore the `xts` package, which will give you access to functions like `apply.daily`, `apply.weekly`, `apply.monthly` and so on which will let you conveniently aggregate your data.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response. As a total newb here I'm not sure what to make of this error, but it's showing up a lot when I attempt to apply your solutions: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Date' not found

Do I need to do something else w/ my cols other than import the CSV? In R studio it looks like it recognizes the headers just fine but...

Comment: @TheNovice, please *edit your question* to include the output of `dput(head(your.actual.data.frame.name))`. It will look like a `structure(....)` with a lot of stuff instead of the `....`. Posting that will help us troubleshoot better.

Comment: that's a lot of output. :) I'll put it up.

Comment: So, this is a bit embarrassing, but it appears R may be case sensitive. Oops. I've got my daily temp average. Any ideas on how to do a seven day rolling average?